# vbscript Wait until Excel is closed before saving

Tags: html, excel, vbscript

i have an html form with an vbscript wich saves the data in an excel-sheet. My problem is that 30 people will use the same html form, so it will happen that two or more will save at the same time.

My Idea is that the vbscript checks if the excel-file is open and when it is waits till it is closed, so it can open it again and save the data, but I have no Idea how to implent that in the code. I have only little knowledge in vbscript and most of my code is gathered through research.

Here is my code so far:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Save in Excel</TITLE></HEAD>
<SCRIPT Language = "VBScript">

Function Export(A,B,C,D,E)

Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
ExcelApp.Visible = True
strPathDoc = "G:\Test.xls"
Set myExcelDoc = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(strPathDoc)
ExcelApp.Visible = True
myExcelDoc.Windows(1).Visible = True
set XlSheet = myExcelDoc.Worksheets(1)
currentRow = 2
currentVal = XlSheet.Range("A" & currentRow).value
While currentVal <> ""
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
    currentVal = XlSheet.Range("A" & currentRow).value
Wend
XlSheet.Range("A" & currentRow).value = A
XlSheet.Range("B" & currentRow).value = B
XlSheet.Range("C" & currentRow).value = C
XlSheet.Range("D" & currentRow).value = D
XlSheet.Range("E" & currentRow).value = E
myExcelDoc.save
myExcelDoc.close
Set myExcelDoc = Nothing
Set ExcelApp = Nothing

End Function



Sub cmdExp_OnClick()
Dim lPrincipal
Dim dblRate

Frstnm = Disnm.value
Lstnm = TreatGrp.value
Mdlnm = TreatGrp2.value
Motnm = TreatGrp3.value
Fatnm = TreatGrp4.value
cInterest = Export(Frstnm, Lstnm, Mdlnm, Motnm, Fatnm)

End Sub

</SCRIPT>
<BODY>
<BR>
Test 1: <INPUT Type="Text" Name="Disnm" Value=""><BR>
Test 2: <INPUT Type="Text" Name="TreatGrp" Value=""><BR>
Test 3: <INPUT Type="Text" Name="TreatGrp2" Value=""><BR>
Test 4: <INPUT Type="Text" Name="TreatGrp3" Value=""><BR>
Test 5: <INPUT Type="Text" Name="TreatGrp4" Value=""><BR>
<INPUT Type="Button" Name="cmdExp" Value="Start">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use Excel as a backend for a web application with concurrent access. Use an actual database (SQL Server Express, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...).

Comment: If you don't intend to use a server-based database such as SQL etc., you may arrange file-based database simply by sharing conventional .mdb file in network folder. Access to that file can be provided within script via ADODB component, as a rule, there is no issues with 30 users simultaneous access to single .mdb.